# How to set unique compound index on json array elements?

Tags: postgresql

I have table `tags` and json column `translations` inside. This column looks like this:

```
translations: [
    { text: "Tag1", language: "en-us" },
    { text: "Tag1_cn", language: "zh-cn" },
    ...
]
```

Is it possible to set unique index on `text+language` across all rows? I would like to prevent inserting tag with same `text+language` to the tags table. So far I was using two tables - `tags` and `tags_translations` however I wanted to avoid extra join when querying for tags.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE jsondemo (blah json);

INSERT INTO jsondemo(blah) VALUES ('[
    { "text": "Tag1", "language": "en-us" },
    { "text": "Tag1_cn", "language": "zh-cn" }]');
```

Comment: I don't think so. You can get the text,language pairs with `SELECT DISTINCT o->>'text', o->>'language' FROM jsondemo, LATERAL json_array_elements(blah) o;`, but because there's >1 element per row a unique index isn't useful here. A custom exclusion constraint might do it, I guess, but I haven't thought about it hard enough for that yet. I suspect you'll need a trigger - and you'll have to `LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` in the trigger to prevent concurrency issues.

Comment: So resuming @Craig comment you exchanged the integrity features of a relational database for the illusory optimization of a JSON mess.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Pretty much. This is why optimisation must be considered and evidence driven.